# How do I ensure a Node.js function only runs once a stream has ended?

Tags: node.js, callback, stream

I'm learning about Node.js in a hurry by trying to recreate some utility applications that I wrote once in C#. I'm sort of confused about what's happening in one of the programs I'm writing. What I want this program to do is open a file on the filesystem, gzip that file, then send the gzipped data off to another server. For testing, I settled on "save the gzipped data to the filesystem, then read it back to verify you got it right."

So what I expect my program to do is:

1. Create the output file.
2. Print "Created test output file".
3. Print "Attempting to re-read the data."
4. Read the file.
5. Output the plain text to the console.

What happens instead:

1. The output file is created.
2. "Attempting to re-read the data." is printed.
3. "Created test output file." is printed.
4. I get no console output.

Here is my code (don't throw stones at me if my style is terrible please!):

```js
var inputFilePath = "data.xml";
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var inputStream = fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath)
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log("Created test output file.");
    });

var gzipStream = zlib.createGzip();
inputStream.pipe(gzipStream);

var outputFile = fs.createWriteStream('output.gzip');
gzipStream.pipe(outputFile);

console.log('Attempting to re-read the data.');
var testInput = fs.createReadStream('output.gzip');
var unzip = zlib.createGunzip();
testInput.pipe(unzip).on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'));
});
```

I'm suspicious the streaming stuff happens asynchronously, which is why I see the console output in a different order than I expected. If that's true, it's a problem as I need the output file to be ready before I try to open it. I noticed `writable.end()` and thought that would be the solution, but I don't understand what happens when I call it in various places:

- If I call `outputFile.end()` before trying to read the file, the output file is empty. I guess this is because it closes the stream before a write happens.
- If I call `gzipStream.end()` instead, I don't get the "Created test output file" message, but one is created!

**edit**

I figured out the second part. In the given code, I should be setting up the handler for the `data` event from the `unzip` stream *before* I call `pipe()`. The way the code is set up now, I'm setting up to handle the event on a stream returned by the pipe, but never reading from THAT stream so my handler is never called.

Comment: Isn't the whole thing about nodejs that it is all asynchronous ?

Comment: Ahh. The way to make it work was inspired by your comment. The trick is to make the parts of the code that require the output file to happen in response to the `end` of inputStream. If you can convert your comment to an answer with an example I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this solution. It looks like conceptually the way to express that I want an order is to say, "When there is no more data in the input stream, start processing the output file it generated." Simplifying greatly:

```
var inputFilePath = "data.xml";
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

function testOutput() {
    console.log('Attempting to re-read the data.');
    var testInput = fs.createReadStream('output.gzip');
    var unzip = zlib.createGunzip();
    unzip.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'))
    });

    testInput.pipe(unzip);
};

// Load input file stream
var inputStream = fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath);

// Pipe the file stream into a gzip stream
var gzipStream = zlib.createGzip();
gzipStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log("Created test output file.");
    testOutput();
});

var outputFile = fs.createWriteStream('output.gzip');
inputStream.pipe(gzipStream).pipe(outputFile);
```

The `pipe()` call empties `inputStream`, then `gzipStream`, which invokes `testOutput()`.